# Sql Azure storage key info

Tags: c#, azure, key, storage

I need to build the secondary key to access storage table
The questions are:

1. Is there a limit of lengths for the secondary storage key?
2. Is there a limit of which characters could be constructed secondary key?
   I.e. could it have ' ',';',':' etc?
   Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about Azure Storage Service Key (for Blobs, Tables and Queues) and not SQL Database (formerly known as SQL Azure), to answer your questions:

- Primary and secondary keys are created by Azure for you. You can't specify these keys. When you create a storage account, these keys are automatically created for you. You could rengenerate either or both of these keys later on any time either programmatically or through Azure Portal.
- These keys are Base64 encoded string and will have all the characters allowed in a Base64 encoded string.